# How to make a left sidebar widget in nature theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress, themes, sidebar

I have a WordPress-installation with this multiple-site-feature.
I use this theme:
http://smthemes.com/demo/nature/
.for all the sites. I just inherit the theme.

Now I want to make it again, and my question is, how do I make a sidebar in the widgets?

On another site with this template inherited, I have a left sidebar in the widget menu:
[image]

But when I want to place something in my new inherited site, there is no `left sidebar` in the widgets-menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe enable "Accessibility Mode" from Appearance/Widgets would do it for you. If not you can use this plugin. I use it to create unlimited sidebars in my websites. its handy and easy to use.
[Custom Sidebars](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-sidebars/)

Comment: Hi,what should the "Accessibility Mode" change? I have enabled it, but not sure what to do then(?)

Comment: Do you see the other siderbars which were missing? if not then give a try via that plugin. Also make sure you don't have any plugin that conflict with these settings. Disabling plugins all at once doesn't hurt